# Use default SignalR connection of Blazor to send "Hello World"

Tags: c#, signalr, blazor

I have a Blazor.NET application (server side) with SignalR hub.
Problem is that I don't know how to customize this or how to use it for communication of connected Clients.

The only function that I found, that will probably make the default settings is in here:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
```

But how can I use SignalR here to send e.g. "Hello World" Message to all connected clients?

Right now in my sample project, when running via Service and connect in Browser I get the following Console output:

```
Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://localhost:5000/_blazor'.
WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:5000/_blazor?id=-ZZJzVxlOPSsRfLmGZZpVw.
```

That Client should catch all SignalR commands and in "Hello World" case should make output in Console.

Is that possible?

Thx!

Comment: The same question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58833063/2224701

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @Jazb - Very useful 